# Return value from Enum in a subclass

Tags: python-3.x

I want to return string value from an Enum which is in a subclass. I have a class structure like this

```
Class1           
  |              
  |--subclass       
  |      |            
  |      |----Enum
```

now I want to return a string value from enum.

I know how to return the value `return str(self.value)`

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

```py
class GSSML:
    class ProsodyAttributes:
        class Rate(Enum):
            def __srt__(self):
                return self.value
            x_slow = 'x-slow'
            slow = 'slow'
            medium = 'medium'
            fast = 'fast'
            x_fast = 'x-fast'
            default = 'default'
```

And my test code

```py
import gssml

def main():
    ssml = gssml.GSSML()
    print(ssml.ProsodyAttributes.Rate.x_fast)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now I would expect it to return `x-fast`
But I get the `Rate.x_fast`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not returning the correct value since you have mis-spelled the dunder method `__str__` to `__srt__`

```
In [15]: from enum import Enum 
    ...:  
    ...: class GSSML: 
    ...:     class ProsodyAttributes: 
    ...:         class Rate(Enum): 
    ...:             def __str__(self): 
    ...:                 return self.value 
    ...:             x_slow = 'x-slow' 
    ...:             slow = 'slow' 
    ...:             medium = 'medium' 
    ...:             fast = 'fast' 
    ...:             x_fast = 'x-fast' 
    ...:             default = 'default' 
    ...:  
    ...: ssml = GSSML() 
    ...: print(ssml.ProsodyAttributes.Rate.x_fast)                                                                                                                                
x-fast
```

Comment: Yes I know `ssml.ProsodyAttributes.Rate.x_fast.value` would return the value. But why is my code not returning string value?

Comment: Understood, see my updated answer @f9fella, you have misspelled `__str__` to `__srt__`